# find the shortestS paths in an unweighted graph by a max flow constraint

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

My problem is that I want to find the shortestS(most possible paths) between a vertex S and T in a graph, but I have a flow constraints too, because the problem state:

-you have a number of ants(or whatever) / a number of rooms / and a number of links between them, I've to send my ants one turn at a time, from S through my graph, to reach T, but all rooms can contains only one ants at a time except for S and T and the ants may not get stuck in a room during several turn.

so I've a flow graph with all the edges with capacity of one (to respect the no more than one ants in each room).

And here I end up with a problem which is between max flow and shortest path, because some shortcuts between two paths could exists, sometimes if I've only one or a little number of ants, that'll be better to take just one path (take the shortcut) and send my ants in single file, but at a certain number of ants it'll be better to take two path, not use the shortcut and send my ants two by two, one in each path, by doing so i'll end up with fewest turn for pass all my ants from S to T.

So far I've found some good algorithms for shortests path, but they always gave me the wrong answer, because they could find blocking flows, meaning take one shortest path instead of two which could have been better, to avoid this problem I've look to max flow problem, with algo like ford fulkerson, because I can track blocking flow and reverse them by looking precisely at if it's worth to reverse a shortcut according to my ants, but there's no notion of weight, so all the shortcut (which will be reverse by max flow algo, because shortcuts are the only things that could cause blocking flow), will be reverse but randomly, so that's harder to prove but i'm pretty sure that that's wrong too, I think it's a better and more precise way to do it than only a shortest path algo, but I'm sure it's again not correct at 100% specifically with graph containing a lot of shorcuts.

So yes it's school work, and I don't want my homework to be done by you, but I really want to go into this subject in depths, and I'm a beginner in all the graph stuff, so I'm interested into any algorithm that could help me, or whatever that could help!

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. Let me try to restate. You want to get N ants through your graph (vertices = rooms, edges = links between rooms) from vertex S to vertex T. Each vertex (except S and T) can only hold 1 ant at a point of time. Going from one room to the next takes 1 time step. How many time steps does it take to get all ants from S to T?

Comment: yes that's it ! and the time steps is exactly what i try to minimize, i want to get my ants from S to T by the fewest time steps possible, and if i try to express my problem, i'd say that according to my number of ants, how do i know if one shorter path is better or not than two longer path.

Comment: This could be a very interesting question, but you didn't specify it with enough detail for us to tell what you really need.   Probably whoever provided the question to you in the first place was more careful, and maybe you could use more of the words that they used.  Regarding your last question in comments:  If you really have to get N ants from S to T as quick as possible, you will use the max flow when you have a lot of ants, and when you get down to fewer ants you will stop using the longer paths.  When you have only 1 or a few ants, you will use the shortest paths only.

Comment: i'm sorry for that, but i think what you said is exactly my problem, only one ant == just find the shortest path, lot of ants == all the distinct paths possible, but between the two how can i find the exact right answer since there is two different problem and resolution for each (shortest path and max flow) (example of [shortcut](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VFe8pr_O5AQa403ZFrlt6MLt7O0QMwdi)), here a simple example of shortcut, but imagine a graph much more complicated whith a lot of different path / shortcut which could all have different length etc, sry if i'm still not clear ..

Comment: If you take the image of shortcut just above, when there's just one ant the exact answer is 3 (meaning by taking the shortcut i've taken three steps of time to get all my ants through S to T), and if i've 10 ants the right answer is 8 (meaning by not taking the shortcut i've taken 8 steps of time to get all my ants through my graph), but that's a simple graph so i'm searching a method to really generalize this to more complicated graph.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right path looking at maximum flow algorithms. You could try the following three step approach:

1. **Rebuild your graph** in order to incorporate your (only one ant per room constraint). This can be done by replacing each room vertex v by two vertices v_1, v_2 and a directed edge e(v_1, v_2) with capacity 1. All incoming edges to v are connected to v_1 instead. All outgoing edges of v are connected to v_2 instead. This way only one ant can go through v (e(v_1, v_2)) at any point in time. Each initial edge between two rooms also gets a capacity of 1.
2. **Run the [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm)**. This should tell you which edges to use in order to maximize the flow. In fact this should give you all distinct paths (where no two paths share a room) from S to T.
3. Once you have the distinct paths, you can calculate their lengths and from that it should be straightforward to calculate the necessary number of steps to get all ants from S to T.

Comment: Yes ! but i think there's a little problem because, you'll have all the distinct paths, but sometime to minimize the time steps, taking a shorcut could be a real gain, example you run Ford-fulkerson algorithm, you end up with a directed graph wich contains two paths (two distinct shortest path), but maybe there's one path going through the two others, wich is very smaller and would have taken less time steps.

Comment: You are right. Ford-fulkerson will only maximize the number of distinct paths in this case but not minimize their lengths. So there might be another solution with the same number of distinct paths but shorter paths which will yield a smaller number of time steps.