# maximum flow algorithm of shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Is there some resources on such algorithm?

I have an unweighted graph (with all edges to one capacity more precisely), and I want to find all the distinct paths between a source and sink vertex(all the paths possible with no one sharing a vertex with another), so I've thought of max-flow problem and algo, but the problem is that I would like to have an algo which permits me to have all the Shortest distinct paths.

Since the max flow algo are just searching with a BFS or something in the residual graph, it will increase randomly my flow( because of the weighting of one, each iteration of a max flow algo will increase my flow of one, which correspond to finding a new distinct path) and i will end up with the maximum number of distinct paths, but I could not end up with the maximum number of distinct shortest paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To get the maximum amount of shortest paths**, how about:

- First do a BFS and assign a number to each node, which would
  denote the distance from the source.
- Then remove all edges between the nodes that have the same number
- Direct the edges, so no flow could move back from higher value nodes to lower value nodes
- Run max flow from source to sink.

Since there is no other option, max flow would always have to only go one step closer to the sink in regards to the shortest path. There could not be any shortest path which is impossible to find after the changes, because any shortest path would have to increase it's next node's value in each step, otherwise there would be another path that was shorter.

Comment: i don't know if i've well understood your answer, but the problem is the shortcut(for example two paths of length 15, and a link between the first vertex of the first path and the last vertex of the second path), my intuition with this problem for now is to first run an algo wich will find all the shortest (with the shortcut) paths, and after run a max flow problem to find all those shortcuts, but here i want to reverse them in the good order (i need to find those shortcut first because sometimes they could be worth for my problem)

Comment: I guess i don't see you mean then after all. Perhaps you can write what the problem is separately from how you approach it, so that it would be easier to understand the issue you are having. Also you could give some examples (like pictures of graphs and what you want to find one those graphs) to clarify.

Comment: do you need to find the maximum amount of distinct paths of a certain length (not the smallest possible)?

Comment: i'm trying to find some example to illustrate my problem but here is my previous question on the subject : [myprevioustopic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421230/find-the-shortests-paths-in-an-unweighted-graph-by-a-max-flow-constraint)  and i add ended up with the idea of finding a max flow algo but with the notion of shortest path.

Comment: Ok, i read your post. You can use linear programming, because you can have fractional flows. For example you can have a flow of ants, that splits into 2 paths (50% go left, 50% go right). So it's simple. 1. You look for how to formulate a max flow problem in linear programming. 2. you find what do you want to maximize minimize (in your case, you want to minimize time, so you have to find a way to calculate time based on the number of ants (time = ants/flow + "weight of all edges used"), where the weight comes from initially filling these pathways) 3. constraints (max flow per room is 1)

Comment: hmm ok i see, i read a little on linear programming at the beginning, when i was looking for some way to solve my problem, and i gave this up because i found these a little tricky, but it seems i'll have to understant linear programming, but thanks for your time and reading my old post though !